# Does the function $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ have a conventional name?

Tags: elementary-functions

I've seen the function $f(x)=\displaystyle \frac{e^x-1}x$ many places, most notably the definition of the Todd class.  Is there a consensus on what it's name is?  I couldn't find one on Wikipedia or Googling, but my brain thinks I knew one at one point.

Comment: The reciprocal of $f$ appears in the definition of [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function).

Comment: $z \cot z =z +\frac{1}{f(2iz)}$

Comment: It seems this function has no name shorter than $\displaystyle \frac{e^x-1}x$.  Well, maybe ${}_1F_1(1,2,x)$.

Comment: It is [Newton's quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_quotient) for $\exp$ at $0$ but that's neither short nor very clear...